# Android do activities require a manifest file?

Tags: java, android, android-activity

So I was wondering if adding multiple activities in my app, do each require a manifest xml file or whatever?
I tried switching activities without it and it crashed.
Then I added the other activity and it worked.
I ask because I hate the use of xml so I try to do everything programatically.

Comment: If you don't like XML then Android development might not be for you. On the plus side, when developing with Eclipse you can do a lot of XML work using the IDE tools rather than having to edit the XML itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to learn to love XML :-) Yes, every activity needs to be declared in the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

Actually android use xml everywhere, manifest, layout, menu, preference, string etc.So get used to it.